# How to pass string and bool variables automatically to directive parent scope

Tags: angularjs, scope, bind

I bind variable in a directive like this :

```
<path-filter-modal is-opened="filterModalIsOpened">
```

And in the directive I use '=' binding like this:

```
scope: {
   isOpened: '='
}
```

When I change variable in directive, a parent scope contains own value.
How can I make that the parent scope contain the same value?

For objects it works well but not with strings and booleans.
Notice that I use controller that is defined in my directive in my directive to change values.

Comment: Do you have sample jsFiddle of the problem?

Comment: `=` should work..please attached a fiddle/plunkr

Comment: "Should work" but only if the directive is used in the same scope as the parent. This is the most common problem in Angular. Google, "put a dot in your models'. Child scopes are created using prototypical inheritance, which is why you need to use an object (hence the dot) as opposed to primitive types (string, number, boolean).

Comment: I thought that it is correct angular behavior.. So I guess it is my code problem. Could you tell me what time variable sets to parent scope? My directive actually contains a modal directive maybe this is the problem? Too much to write in fiddle to show..

Comment: @SunilD. OP's code defines `isolated scope`, which is obviously not the same scope as parent...

Comment: @Joy isolate scopes are not created through prototypical inheritance. Only child scopes: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Because JavaScript is designed to be so.**

Defining an isolate scope in the directive creates a new `$scope` object, which is a separate `$scope` object. Its only relationship with the parent scope is that: `$isolateScope.$parent === $parentScope`. **It doesn't inherits from `$parentScope` prototypical.**

- When you assign some primitive type (string/boolean) to `$scope.isOpened`, actually JavaScript engine will create a **new** variable `isOpened` on `$scope`. It is totally not related to `$parentScope.isOpened`.

  But now, Angular syncs the two variables for you implicitly. So binding primitive variables still makes `two-way binding` work well. Please check [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g0cq47pr/).
- If you binds to some object type, the child scope and parent scope are referencing to the exactly **the same copy** of an object in the memory. Changing on the parent scope will change the child scope automatically. So `two-way binding` is always recommended to bind objects, not primitive types.

Check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g0cq47pr/1/). I bind a primitive and an object to the directive `myDirective`. Then modify them inside the `link` function:

```
scope.primitiveParam = 'primitive from directive';
// $parent.primitive and primitiveParam refer to different memory; 
// Angular is responsible to sync them.
console.log(scope.$parent.primitive);
console.log(scope.primitiveParam);

scope.objectParam.name = 'object from directive';
// $parent.obj and objectParam refer to an identical object
console.log(scope.$parent.obj.name);
console.log(scope.objectParam.name);

console.log(scope.objectParam === scope.$parent.obj);
```

And the result is like:

```
primitive from parent
primitive from directive
object from directive
object from directive
```

For more details: [Understanding Scopes](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes) (here are many intuitive images illustrating the concepts clearly)

Comment: Thats what I thought too but people above tell me that for strings and bools it should work too.

Comment: Ok I undestand what is the problem but you are not right. Directive isolated scope takes values directly not from prototype. It takes objects by link.

Comment: @Joy `=` two way binding does support for primitives..if you are using `=` in isolated scope and passing that scope reference through attribute

Comment: @PankajParkar Thank you very much. I missed some point there. I have updated the answer.

Comment: @Joy sorry to say..but still feels like you should read prototypal inheritance concept again..

Answer (score 1):

RE: For objects it works well but not with strings and booleans

I think it's the usual case of prototypal inheritance problem. When the model come from object it works well, but if it come from non-objects there's a possibility that the ng-model is created on child scope.

To solve that problem, use modern approach, use `Controller as` approach. Or put the filterModelIsOpened in an object. The first approach is better.

```
 <div ng-controller="SomeController as s">
     <path-filter-modal is-opened="s.filterModalIsOpened">
 </div>


  function SomeController() { // no need to use $scope
      this.filterModalIsOpened = false;
  }
```

Or if you are using older version of Angular, you cannot use `Controller as` approach. Just create your own alias in the controller:

```
 <div ng-controller="SomeController">
     <path-filter-modal is-opened="s.filterModalIsOpened">
 </div>


  function SomeController($scope) { 
      $scope["s"] = this;
      this.filterModalIsOpened = false;
  }
```

Here's a good article explaining the prototypal inheritance: http://codetunnel.io/angularjs-controller-as-or-scope/

---

Here are the demo why you should ***always*** prefix your model, be they are object or primitive.

Not recommended. Live code demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hdks813z/1/

```
<div ng-app="App" ng-controller="Ctrl">

    <div ng-if="true">    
           <input type="checkbox" ng-model="filterModalCanBeOpened"/>
           <the-directive primitive-param="filterModalCanBeOpened"></the-directive>
    </div>    

    <hr/>
    <p>
    The value below doesn't react to changes in primitive(non-object) property 
    that is created a copy on a directive(e.g., ng-repeat, ng-if) that creates 
    child scope
    </p>    
    $scope.primitive: {{filterModalCanBeOpened}} 

</div>

angular.module('App', [])
    .directive('theDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: {
            primitiveParam: '='            
        },
        template: '<div>primitiveParam from directive: {{ primitiveParam }}; </div>',
        link: function (scope) {            
        }
    };
})
.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.filterModalCanBeOpened = true;
}]);
```

Recommended: Live code demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2rpv27kt/

```
<div ng-app="App" ng-controller="Ctrl as c">

    <div ng-if="true">    
           <input type="checkbox" ng-model="c.filterModalCanBeOpened"/>
           <the-directive primitive-param="c.filterModalCanBeOpened"></the-directive>
    </div>    

    <hr/>
    <p>
    The value below react to changes in primitive(non-object) property that is 
    addressed directly by its alias c, creating child scope on it would be 
    impossible. So the primitive below react to changes on 
    the c's filterModalCanBeOpened.
    </p>    
    c.primitive: {{c.filterModalCanBeOpened}} 

</div>

angular.module('App', [])
    .directive('theDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: {
            primitiveParam: '='            
        },
        template: '<div>primitiveParam from directive: {{ primitiveParam }}; </div>',
        link: function (scope) {            
        }
    };
})
.controller('Ctrl', [function () {
    this.filterModalCanBeOpened = true;
}]);
```

Comment: Updated my question. I have to controllers. First is route controller and another one is defined in directive. So in my case I have the same implementation except the controller implementation place. So, I think it is correct angular behavior, isn't it? (parent route controller doesn't take bool and string values)

Comment: "I think it's the usual case of prototypal inheritance problem." It is not, an isolated scope takes objects directly from a parent by link. So this is why I get not changed values.